# Change the title string of a setting defined via iOS settings bundle at run time?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, settings-bundle, ios-settings-bundle

I'm working on an iPad application that allows users to log in using Touch ID. Also I've included a preference called "Touch ID" in application settings bundle where users can switch on/off that option to enable or disable Touch ID authentication.

The following plist file is what I used to set up the settings bundle.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>StringsTable</key>
    <string>Root</string>
    <key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSToggleSwitchSpecifier</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Touch ID</string>
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>settingsTouchID</string>
            <key>DefaultValue</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The following image is the screenshot of the application settings screen.

[image: App settings screen]

However, certain iPads feature "Face ID" instead of "Touch ID," and I'd like to provide the option name (title field in the Plist file) for setting bundle to "Face ID" instead of "Touch ID" for those devices.

Could someone kindly inform me if dynamic titles for the application settings options are possible?

Note: I have got some alternative solutions like, creating a settings screen within my app itself, renaming the setting name to a generic one, etc.

Comment: You should build this preference into a Settings screen within your app.  You can see that once Face ID access is granted in your code, that it appears on the Settings screen (right above Siri & Search in your screenshot) so that the user can disable it if they choose.  You wouldn't want two different settings that read "Face ID".  Alternatively, you could simply label your setting something like "Biometric authentication".

Comment: @CSmith - Thank you very much for your valuable suggestions. I think, I have already found the suggested work arounds from other posts (sorry, the In-app settings were not present in the "Note:" write-up at the time when I posted this question) but I am curious to do with the settings bundle as I have similar requirements where it requires dynamic titles for the settings bundle. Thank you again for your valuable time and appreciating the suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no way to edit plist files at run time

Comment: @Shahabaz: As of now, I'm considering this answer as accepted until some one comes with a solution to do so. Thank you.